# NLog not working with MSTest, where should the config go?

Tags: mstest, nlog

We have recently migrated tests from NUnit to MSTest and I am struggling to get previously passing tests runnning. From what I can deduce MSTest cannot detect the NLog configuration. 
I have my Nlog configuration in my App.config which didn't cauise an issue with NUnit.

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the **`Copy to Output Directory`** setting for your App.config to **`Copy Always`** or **`Copy if Newer`**. More on this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vststest/thread/3e520735-8ced-4092-b681-38b69e0db534/).

[image: Example of a Unit Test Project]