# NUnit3 multiple App.config files in Teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, integration-testing, app-config

I'm having a strange problem. I have a bunch of integration tests projects. Each test project has a configuration file (app.config).

Currently, in my "Run Integration Tests" build step, the NUnit3 console runner allows me to specify only one config file (where it says "Path to application configuration file"). I have specified the path to one of my integration test app.configs. The problem is, the tests in other test projects fail because the Nunit3 console doesn't recognize their app.config files.

How can I have TeamCity run each test project with its own app.config file in its bin/release folder?

FYI: This is what I have specified in the NUnit assembly lookup: `**\bin\Release\*.Integration.Tests.dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, [this was my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25067629/5908918). After removing all references between my test projects, I noticed that the build time was reduced by 50%.